# Proving a periodic transcendental entire function is bounded on a straight line

Tags: complex-analysis

For a non-constant transcendental  entire function $f$ and distinct constants $a$ and $b,$

suppose that $f(z)-az$ and $f(z)-bz$ are periodic with periods $x$ and $y$ respectively.

I have to show that $f(z)-az$ and $f(z)-bz$ are both bounded on a straight line.

Attempt:  since $f(z)-az$ and $f(z)-bz $ are periodic with periods $x$ and $y$ respectively, we find that $f'(z)$ has periods $x$ and $y$ and hence either $x/y$ is a real number or $f'(z)$ is a constant.

I am stuck here.

Comment: If $x/y$ is not rational then $f'$ is constant (why ? $x/y$ real or $x/y$ complex..) and $f(z) = uz+v, u=a=b$. If $x/y$ is rational then we have $x = nt, y = mt, f'$ is $t$-periodic, $d = \int_0^t f'(z)dz, a = nd,b = md$, which means $f(z) = \sum_k c_k e^{2i \pi k z/t}$ with $c_0 = d/t$ and $\forall r > 0,c_k= o(r^{|k|})$.

Comment: I didn't understand what you are try to say. Also why you are taking $f(z)= uz + v $ which is not possible since $f(z)$ is given to be transcendental.

Comment: But this would mean that $f(z)$ is linear which violates the hypothesis that $f(z)$ is transcendental.

Comment: $f'$ constant implies $f(z) = uz+v$. And (in the case $x/y$ rational) I meant $f'(z) = \sum_k c_k e^{2i \pi k z/t},  f(z) = C+c_0 z + \sum_{k \ne 1} \frac{c_k}{2i \pi k/t} e^{2i \pi k z/t}$

Comment: Can you please elaborate how $f'(z)$ has such particular form.

Comment: What do you not understand